# How to solve error "CCNode, selector xxx was already scheduled

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to build simple game (with help from online tutorial) that imitate conway's game of life. I put grid on screen.

When user tap into grid, it will disable/enable the dots, and when user clicked play button, dots on grid will evolve based on conway's game of life rules.

however there is a problem, after all code done, and I tried to run a simulation ( I enable some dots on grid).

and clicked play button, nothing happened, I clicked play button twice, and Xcode logged out this message:

```
GameOfLife2[823:43706] -[CCNode schedule:interval:repeat:delay:] : Selector 'step1' was already scheduled on <MainScene = 0x7fca01e69590 | Name = >
```

for details about few of my methods related to this error (posted on Mainscene.m)

```
#import "MainScene.h"
#import "Grid.h"

@implementation MainScene {
    Grid *_grid;
    CCTimer *_timer;
    CCLabelTTF *_generationLabel;
    CCLabelTTF *_populationLabel;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _timer = [[CCTimer alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)play
{

     [self schedule:@selector(step1) interval:0.05f];}

- (void)pause
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(step1)];
}


- (void)step1
{
    [_grid evolveStep];
    _generationLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _grid.generation];
    _populationLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _grid.totalAlive];
}

@end
```

on Grid.m

```
 -(void)evolveStep{

    [self countNeighbors];

    [self updateCreatures];

    _generation++;
}

-(void)countNeighbors
{

    for (int i = 0; i < [_gridArray count]; i++)
    {


        for (int j = 0; j < [_gridArray[i] count]; j++)
        {


            Creature *currentCreature = _gridArray[i][j];


            currentCreature.livingNeighbors = 0;

            for (int x = (i-1) ; x <= (i+1); x++)
            {
                for (int y = (j-1); y <= (j+1); y++)
                {

                    BOOL isIndexValid;

                    isIndexValid = [self isIndexValidForX:x andY:y];


                    if (!((x == i) && (y == j)) && isIndexValid)
                    {
                        Creature *neighbor = _gridArray[x][y];

                        if (neighbor.isAlive)
                        {
                            currentCreature.livingNeighbors +=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

-(void)updateCreatures{

    _totalAlive = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l <= [_gridArray count]; l++) {

        for (int k = 0; [_gridArray[l] count]; k++) {
            Creature *currentCreature = _gridArray[l][k];

            if (currentCreature.livingNeighbors == 3) {
                currentCreature.isAlive = YES;
            } else if ( (currentCreature.livingNeighbors <= 1) || (currentCreature.livingNeighbors >= 4) ) {
                currentCreature.isAlive = NO;
            }
            if (currentCreature.isAlive) {
                _totalAlive++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

tried to google out this problem, still no solutions yet.

Comment: post all the code where you schedule the step1 selector. Note that you should not create a CCTimer object yourself, instead use the CCNode schedule* methods and, if needed, keep a reference to the returned CCTimer instance. See: http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCTimer.html

Comment: ok, already posted. few moments ago, I also downloaded master files from online site, and it just worked out, while mine was stopped on this problem.

Comment: then what should I do to make the step work?

Comment: play/pause are unnecessary, you just schedule the selector once. If you want to pause it, change the node's pause property, ie: `self.paused = YES`